# How to make popup window in Liferay?

Tags: javascript, liferay

How to make popup window in Liferay?
This my code. It's like in Liferay Wiki.

```
var popup = new Liferay.Popup( { 
  header: 'our title', 
  position:[150,150], 
  modal:true, width:500, 
  height:300, 
  xy: ['center', 100], 
  url: '/my_file.jsp', 
  urlData: { winowState : 'LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE'} 
} );
```

What is missing?

**PS: I'm trying to put it working in  Liferay 6.0**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On top of sandeepnair85's answer, to AJAX in content form your URI, you'll have to add the following code:

```
<aui:script use="aui-dialog">
    function showPopup(){
        var dialog = new A.Dialog({
            title: 'DISPLAY CONTENT',
            centered: true,
            modal: true,
            width: 200,
            height: 200
        }).plug(A.Plugin.IO, {
            uri: 'http://myurl.com'
        }).render();
    }
</aui:script>
```

More details on how the A.Plugin.IO plugin works can be found here:
http://alloy.liferay.com/deploy/api/A.Plugin.IO.html

Comment: My brother helped me to find solution to my problem... it's almost the same as your answer, but instead of 'http://myurl.com' it has  '<%=renderRequest.getContextPath() %>/my_file' and also I had configured bad web.xml file. It must to include this configuration:

<servlet>
<servlet-name>my_file</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/liftbox/my_file.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>my_file</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/my_file</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Comment: No problem! I simply put `myurl.com` as a placeholder for you to put the actual url to the resource you need.

Answer (score 1):

Hi can you try this code. Its a simple example on how to create popup in liferay usin AUI

```
<aui:script use="aui-dialog">
    function showPopup(){
        var dialog = new A.Dialog({
            title: 'DISPLAY CONTENT',
            centered: true,
            modal: true,
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            bodyContent: "My First popup"
        }).render();
    }
</aui:script>
```

Comment: I had tried your solution,but instead of bodyContent I use uri and I'm getting error in JavaScript. this is the error Uncaught ReferenceError: test_content is not defined. Where test_content is the content of page that I want to access